# Reversing a stack implemented using a linked list

Tags: c++

This is a very simple program that implements a stack using a linked list. **Kindly help me figure out the logical bug that makes the program crash on run.**

```
class LLStack {
    public:
        struct Node {
            int data;
            Node* next;
            Node(int n) {
                data = n;
                next = 0;
            }
            Node(int n, Node* node) {
                data = n;
                next = node;
            }
        };
        LLStack();
        LLStack(const LLStack&);
        LLStack& operator = (const LLStack&);
        ~LLStack();
        void push(int);
        int pop();
        int top();
        bool isEmpty();
        void flush();

    private:
        Node* head;

};

LLStack::LLStack() {
    head = 0;
}

LLStack::LLStack(const LLStack& s) {
    head = new Node(NULL);
    head->data = s.head->data;
    head->next = new Node(*(s.head->next));
}

LLStack::~LLStack() {
    this->flush();
}

LLStack& LLStack::operator = (const LLStack& s) {
    this->head = new Node(NULL);
    this->head->data = s.head->data;
    this->head->next = new Node(*(s.head->next));
    return *this;
}

void LLStack::push(int x) {
    if (head == 0) head = new Node(x);
    else {
        Node* temp = new Node(x, head);
        head = temp;
    }
}

int LLStack::pop() {
    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements to pop\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        Node* temp = head;
        int n = temp->data;
        head = temp->next;
        delete temp;
        return n;
    }
}

int LLStack::top() {
    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the stack\n\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return head->data;
    }
}

bool LLStack::isEmpty() {
    return (head == 0);
}

void LLStack::flush() {

    if (head == 0) {
        cout << "\n\nNo elements in the Stack to flush\n\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << "\n\nFlushing the Stack:  ";
    Node* temp = 0;
    while (head != 0) {
        temp = head;
        cout << temp->data << "  ";
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

This is the trouble-maker fuction:

```
void reverseStack(LLStack& s1) {
    LLStack s2;
    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
        s2.push(s1.pop());
    }
    s1 = s2;
}

int main() {

    LLStack s;
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
    s.push(4);
    s.push(5);
    reverseStack(s);
    cout << "\n\nFlushing s:\n";
    s.flush();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have implemented my own copy constructor and the copy assignment operator. I don't understand why it crashes on run. On flushing it displays garbage values before crashing.

Comment: You don't have to check everything. It's only the reverseStack function that makes it crash. Please just check that.

Comment: So no usable error log to help us help you?

Comment: You've figured out `cout`. Wouldn't step 1 be adding some `cout`s to `reverseStack()` to see which bit causes an issue?

Comment: i assume, that problem might be in your copy constructor. for example, when you dereference `*(s.head->next)`, that might be NULL.

Comment: The problem occurs after returning from the reverseStack function, when trying to call flush(). How to fix it?

Comment: Well, what does `flush()` look like?

Comment: It's there in the question. I have posed the entire code.

Comment: Please help me out...:(

Comment: Flush should print all 5 values. But it prints the first two and then prints garbage as the third and then crash! :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your copy assignment operator. Consider:

```
void reverseStack(LLStack& s1) {
    LLStack s2;
    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
        s2.push(s1.pop());
    }
    s1 = s2;
}
```

Everything works fine until you return from the function, at which point the destructor for `s2` is called. The destructor calls `flush()`, which deletes all stack elements of `s2`. In your copy assignment operator (and copy constructor, at that), you create two nodes: `head` and `head->next`; the rest of the nodes are shared between the two stacks, so after `s2` has been deleted, `s1.head->next->next` points to a node that has been deleted, but you still try to access it.

The solution is to have the copy assignment operator (and the copy constructor) create a proper deep copy of the stack, not just the first two elements, like this (also takes care of self assignment):

```
LLStack& LLStack::operator=(const LLStack& s) {
    if (this==&s) return *this; // self assignment
    flush();  // avoid memory leak
    head = new Node(*s.head);
    Node* s_ptr = s.head;
    Node* t_ptr = head;
    while (s_ptr->next) {
        t_ptr->next = new Node(*s_ptr->next);
        s_ptr = s_ptr->next;
        t_ptr = t_ptr->next;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Remember that the copy constructor should do the same.